# Combining two columns from a query into one in DataGrid (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, oledb

I have two columns in the **Access** database that I would like to combine.  One is `Street Name` and the other is `Direction`.  So, if Street Name has value of `Diamond St`. and Direction has `W`, I'd like to be able to combine it into `W Diamon St`.  Is there a quick and easy way to do this?  I figured I'd ask before I do what I planned, which involves combining the two strings in a list and then binding the column to that list.

Is there anything that can be done in query?  For example my query is

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Date, Time, Street, Direction FROM Event", con);
```

I can't figure out how I can do `Street, Direction AS StreetDir` in that query, since I have multiple items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is for display only you could concatenate the two columns within the sql string:

`Select rtrim(ltrim(isnull(column1,'') + ' ' + isnull(column2,''))) as columnname from table`

**Edit:**

For **Access** SQL:

```
SELECT Date, Time, 

Trim(iif(isnull(Street),'',Street) & ' ' & iif(isnull(direction),'',direction)) 

as StreetDir FROM Event
```

Comment: This throws an error saying wrong number of arguments were used.

Comment: Can you debug the code to see exactly where the error is being thrown? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: The query is exactly as in my original post.  I just add your code into it.

Comment: Is this what you code looks like: `OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Date, Time, RTrim(LTrim(isnull(Street,'') + ' ' + isnull(direction,''))) as Street_Direction FROM Event", con);`. The error sound like you are missing the comma between the sql and the connection(con).

Comment: Sorry instead of the plus signs(+) try using the ampersand (&).

Comment: Sorry again I'm not use to SQL for Access. Try the following:  `SELECT Date, Time, Trim(isnull(Street,'') & ' ' & isnull(direction,'')) as Street_Direction FROM Event`

Comment: I get the same exact error.  Says Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'Trim(isnull(Street,'') & '' & isnull(Direction,''))'

Comment: Try this:   `SELECT Date, Time, 

Trim(iif(isnull(Street),'',Street) & ' ' & iif(isnull(direction),'',direction)) 

as StreetDir FROM Event `

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so very much!  Update your original answer so that others looking for the solution would find it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Write a Converter to return whatever value you want. i.e while Binding the GridColumns, create the GridTemplateColumn and in celltemplate,you can do

   ```
     <DataGridTemplateColumn  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"  />
                 </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   ```

and in converter's Convert method you can return the Combine value of two properties

2.Create a calculative property in your model to combine two string property and bind your column to it.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail?